# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: xxx\resources\views\admin\info-admin.blade.php) http://127.0.0.1:8000/tambah-info

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Invalid argument supplied foreach()when try to add data

here's the form for submitting the data

**info-admin.blade.php**

```
<tbody class="text-center align-middle">
    @foreach ( $info as $infos )
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="align-middle">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $infos->judul }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $infos->konten }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $infos->image }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $infos->created_at }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $infos->Updated_at }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle form">
                <a href="{{ route('infos.edit', [$infos->id]) }}"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info mb-3">Edit</button></a>
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('infos.destroy', [$infos->id]) }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Hapus</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Store logic

**InfosController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $info = new Info();

    $info->judul = $request->input('judul');
    $info->konten = $request->input('konten');
    $info->image = $request->input('image');

    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $file = $request->file('image');
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move('upload/info_penting' , $filename);
        $info->image = $filename;
    } else{
        return $request;
        $info->image = '';
    }

    $info->save();

    return view('admin.info-admin')->with('info','$info');
}
```

my routes, in case if you want to see it

**web.php**

```
route::post('/tambah-info','InfosController@store')->middleware('auth','admin');
```

***EDITED***
undefined variable when trying to update

the controller for the logic for updating the data
**InfosController**

```
public function update(Request $request, Info $info)
    {
        //
        Info::where('id', $info->id)
            ->update([

                'judul' => $request->judul,
                'konten' => $request->konten,
                'image' => $request->image,
            ]);

        return redirect('/info-admin')->with('success', 'Berhasil Diedit');
    }
```

here's the form for for the updating the data
**edit-info.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('infos.update', [$info->id]) }}" method="patch" enctype="multipart/form-data>
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
            <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="judul">Judul</label>
            <input type="string" class="form-control" value="{{$info->judul}}" id="judul" name="judul" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Kolom Wajib Diisi
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Konten</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" value="{{$info->konten}} id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" name="konten" required></textarea>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Kolom Wajib Diisi
                </div>
            </div>
            <input class="mb-3" type="file"value="{{$info->image}} name="image">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block mt-auto">Kirim</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are passing a single eloquent instance to the view, where `foreach` loop expects an array or collection of objects. [Assuming you have `get` route and its controller method for `'/tambah-info'` and the error occurs after form submission.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After saving your post, you should redirect to another route, probably the route for displaying all the posts

```
return redirect()->route('info-admin');
```

You should have another controller method for displaying all your data, you will have something similar to this

```
public function index()
{
    $infos = Info::all();
    return view('admin.info-admin', ['infos' => $infos]);
}
```

Then for sending a collection to the view. You should use your foreach this way and not the other way

```
@foreach($infos as $info)
// your code here
@endforeach
```

**UPDATES**

Your admin view should be like this

```
<tbody class="text-center align-middle">
    @foreach ( $infos as $info )
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="align-middle">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $info->judul }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $info->konten }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $info->image }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $info->created_at }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $info->updated_at }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle form">
                <a href="{{ route('infos.edit', ['infos' => $info->id]) }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info mb-3">Edit</button></a>
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('infos.destroy', $info->id) }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Hapus</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

**Add data**
define two routes, one route to access the form and another route to store form data

```
Route::get('/add-info', 'InfosController@create)->name('infos.add');
Route::post('/store-info', 'InfosController@store)->name('infos.store');
```

Access your add form as

```
<a href="{{ route('infos.add') }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-Success mb-3">Add</button></a>
```

Your create method

```
public function create()
{
   return view('infos.add');
}
```

Your store method

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $info = new Info();

        $info->judul = $request->input('judul');
        $info->konten = $request->input('konten');
        $info->image = $request->input('image');

        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $file = $request->file('image');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('upload/info_penting' , $filename);
            $info->image = $filename;
        } else{
            return $request;
            $info->image = '';
        }
        $info->save();
        return redirect()->route('admin.info-admin');
```

**Edit data**
define two routes, one route to access the form and another route to update form data

```
Route::get('/edit-info/{infos}/edit', 'InfosController@edit')->name('infos.edit');
Route::post('/update-info/{infos}/update', 'InfosController@update)->name('infos.update');
```

Access your edit form as

```
<a href="{{ route('infos.edit', ['infos' => $info->id]) }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-Success mb-3">Edit</button></a>
```

Your edit method

```
public function edit($id)
{
$info = Info::findOrFail($id)
return view('infos.edit', ['infos' => $info]);
}
```

Your update method

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
        Info::where('id', $id)
            ->update([

                'judul' => $request->judul,
                'konten' => $request->konten,
                'image' => $request->image,
            ]);
        return redirect()->route('admin.info-admin')->with('success', 'Berhasil Diedit');
}
```

**Add form action**

```
<form action="{{ route('infos.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Edit form action**

```
<form action="{{ route('infos.update', ['infos' => $info->id]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203438/discussion-on-answer-by-abiola-invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach-view-xx).

Comment: @Abiola how to use string limit? `p class="card-text">{{ $info->konten}}</p>`

Comment: You can define an accessor in your Info model `public function getBodyHtmlAttribute() {
  return str_limit(strip_tags($this->body), 250); 
} ` which you can use in your view as `$info->body_html`